# how do sql join limit on one of the tables

Tags: php, sql, join

I want to ask how sql join uses limits on one table

I have searched Google but the query I did was different and that made me confused

```
$queryAnime = "SELECT *
    FROM `anime` 
    JOIN `episode` ON `anime`.`link` = `episode`.`idanime`
    ORDER BY `anime`.`id` DESC
";

$anime = $this->db->query($queryAnime)->result_array();
```

when I add a limit in the normal way only 1 array appears
I let 'anime' appear all and 'episodes' only show one array

and sorry my English is bad I hope you understand and dabat helps me

Comment: show the result you get and the result you expect

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When describing a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to specify the columns you need in the Select statements and not use *, and use a Select Distinct

So for example

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `show_name`,`eposode`
            FROM `anime` JOIN `episode`
            ON `anime`.`link` = `episode`.`idanime`
            ORDER BY `anime`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: An unclear question should get a comment asking for a clarifying edit & be closed, it should not be answered.